# RoR: devise и валидация полей

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Добавил в модель user поля  + валидацию для них

```
#user.rb
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /.+@.+\..+/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not at email")
    end
  end
end

class PhoneValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /^((|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not at phone")
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :adverts

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :email_publ, email: true
  validates :phone_publ, phone: true
  validates :name_publ, length: { maximum: 20 }

end
```

контроллер

```
# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_user, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    respond_with(@user)
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to user_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
    else
       render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def load_user
      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role, :name_publ, :email_publ, :phone_publ, :avatar)
    end

end
```

Теперь при регистрации ошибки "Email publ is not at email" и "Phone publ is not at phone". Добавленные поля при регистрации не нужны, поэтому в форму регистрации они не выводятся. Валидация по ним нужна при редактировании профиля пользователем или при его создании админом.

Как можно убрать валидацию этих полей из формы регистрации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит внимательнее читать описание гема на Github. Так написаны инструкции по валидации, добавлении ["строгих параметров"](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) и проч.
Зачем проводить валидацию email собственноручно, когда Devise делает это за Вас? В конфигурациях Devise можно задать RegExp для этого.

Comment: спасибо. как обычно мануалы читаю не внимательно.

Comment: strong-parameters позволяют добавить свои поля в форму регистрации. и успешно проходить валидацию. у меня другая проблема. новые поля при регистрации не требуются. но валидация по ним почему то все равно идет в этой форме. как ее можно отключить?

Comment: Для этого в рельсе есть атрибут 'on' для оператора валидаций: 'validates :phone, :presence => true, :on => :update'

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.